# How can I add subtitles to movie using flowplayer module?

Tags: drupal, flowplayer

I'm using flowplayer module to play videos on my site. I would like to add sutitles to some of the movies. How can I do it in Drupal?
I tried to add them like this:

```
$flowplayer = array(
'clip' => array(
    'url' => str_replace('sites/default/files/videos', 'http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/videos', $node->field_video[0]['filepath']),
    'captionURL' => str_replace('sites/default/files/videos', 'http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/videos', $node->field_caption[0]['filepath'])

),
....
```

Then the output is:

```
<param value="config={"clip":{"url":"http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/videos/video.flv","captionURL":"http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/videos/subtitles.srt","scaling":"fit"},...
```

However it says no stream found. When I erase "clip", the video is found.But how can I add subtitles?
I wonder if I need some plugin or what is wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using str_replace and hardcoding the domain url, you can use `global $base_path` to get the domain name for your drupal installation. You can also use the `url()` function and ask for an absolute url. This is a more robust solution, I don't know how to solve the actual problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to have more than one video? You might try using the playlist param which has support for titles. I'm not sure how you would display them (i'm doing something very similar at the moment, hopefully this is helpful). I'm using the Flowplayer API module but the js syntax should be similar.

```
$player = theme('flowplayer',array(
                                    'clip' => array(
                                        'duration' => 5,
                                        'autoPlay' => true
                                    ),
                                    'playlist' => array(
                                        array('url' =>'http://localhost/episode_18.mp4','title' => 'Episode 18'),
                                        array('url' =>'http://localhost/episode_19.mp4','title' => 'Episode 19'),
                                        array('url' =>'http://localhost/6.jpg','title' => 'Image')
                                ),
                                'plugins' => array(
                                        'controls' => array(
                                            'playlist' => true
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            );
    return $player;
```